# Shorthand notation for numpy.array()

Tags: python, numpy

Are there any accepted shorthand notations for `numpy.array()`?  For me the biggest drawback of using numpy, as compared to dedicated numerical langages, is that there is no compact notation for array creation.

My typical verbose usage would be:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3])
```

Can anyone provide examples of shorthand notation for numpy array creation as used in existing mature projects?

Comment: If you find `np.array()` too taxing to type or look at (really?), you could always wrap it in a shorter-named function. Whether this would be an improvement is debatable.

Comment: You could define some shorthand function like `AR = np.array` and then call that instead.  But this may confuse readers of your code.  Anyway, it's a bit odd to have lots of literal `np.array` calls.  Usually you are reading the data from somewhere else or calculating it, not typing it directly into an array call in your code.

Comment: I write a lot of physics based simulation code, so I do end up creating a lot of arrays on the fly and often have to convert user driven input data into numpy arrays.  This can sometimes get really verbose when multiple arrays are involved in the equations I am using.  I have certainly thought about defining a shorthand function the way you suggested (or doing something like `from numpy import array as A`), but as far as I know this is non-standard, which is bad for readability.

Comment: You could abuse `r_` -- `r_[1,2,3] == array([1,2,3])` -- but that will be a lot slower.

Comment: While I understand the concerns raised, this is a valid question for someone doing interactive work at a python prompt.  Contrast with Matlab (and probabaly R) that have direct array creation m = [1,2,3].

Comment: **reopen** Having a shorthand for array creation is something that would be useful. In fact, one does exist, but is little-known: `r_[1,2,3]` is short for `array([1,2,3])`

Comment: I logged in just to downvote this question, which is literally against the good coding practices of Python.

Answer (score 3):

Based on [DSM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/487339/dsm)'s comment, here is a possible short hand:

One could first define the following:

```
import numpy as np
class ShorthandArray(object):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if isinstance(key, tuple):
            return np.array(key)
        else:
            return np.array([key])

_ = ShorthandArray()
```

Now array creation can be now be done using:

```
a = _[1,2,3]
```

This will also work for multi-dimensional arrays:

```
a = _[[1,2,3]]
```

This is certainly compact, but is totally non-standard python notation.  Brackets are meant for item access, not for class creation.  I can see this potentially creating a great deal of confusion.

Comment: One could use a letter instead of the underscore, but then this notation looks exactly like array access, which I find more confusing.

Comment: How awful, I hope I never encounter such a thing in a real code. On the other hand that's a fun answer.

Comment: I agree.  I have never actually used this.